# How to create a hash or dictionary object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to create a map object in javascript. I came to the following idea:

```
 var a = new Array();
 a["key1"] = "value1";
 a["key2"] = "value2";
```

but then how I can find if a particular key exists or not?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Don't use an array if you want named keys, use a plain object.

```
var a = {};
a["key1"] = "value1";
a["key2"] = "value2";
```

Then:

```
if ("key1" in a) {
   // something
} else {
   // something else 
}
```

Comment: How to push a new key later in the  "a".  Will a.push({"key3","value3"})      work?

Comment: *push* is an array method, and you have a plain object here. There's no restriction on when you can modify the object and you can use the same syntax as in the answer:
`a["key3"] = "value3";`

Comment: Syntax could be shortened to `var a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};`

Comment: How can i remove the element using key?

Comment: @DushyantBangal `del a["key1"]` or `del a.key1`

Comment: This is not `hasOwnProperty` safe. Using `in` like this could lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: This cannot gaurentee iteration order incase you want to iterate it

Answer (score 42):

A built-in Map type is now available in JavaScript. It can be used instead of simply using Object. It is supported by current versions of all major browsers.

Maps do not support the `[subscript]` notation used by Objects. That syntax implicitly casts the `subscript` value to a primitive string or symbol. Maps support any values as keys, so you must use the methods `.get(key)`, `.set(key, value)` and `.has(key)`.

```js
var m = new Map();
var key1 = 'key1';
var key2 = {};
var key3 = {};

m.set(key1, 'value1');
m.set(key2, 'value2');

console.assert(m.has(key2), "m should contain key2.");
console.assert(!m.has(key3), "m should not contain key3.");
```

Objects only supports primitive strings and symbols as keys, because the values are stored as properties. If you were using Object, it wouldn't be able to to distinguish `key2` and `key3` because their string representations would be the same:

```js
var o = new Object();
var key1 = 'key1';
var key2 = {};
var key3 = {};

o[key1] = 'value1';
o[key2] = 'value2';

console.assert(o.hasOwnProperty(key2), "o should contain key2.");
console.assert(!o.hasOwnProperty(key3), "o should not contain key3."); // Fails!
```

#### Related

- MDN Documentation: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet)

Comment: you should careful since this is an "experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) proposal"

Comment: someMap.set(key, val) didn't work in nodejs

Comment: @sports You're right, Node.js doesn't have many newer features enabled by default (yet!). It is enabled if you set the `node --harmony` flag, and is enabled by default in IO.js.

Comment: @Ghashange The proposal has since been standardized, and is supported in current versions of all browsers. :)

Comment: `Map` on Chrome is painfullt slow, even to get an attribute, and furthermore, as you say, its interface is completely incompatible with normal javascript objects. For example, you can't use `a[key]` and `Object.keys()`. I do not recommend to use it.

Comment: It is also not working in IE11. You can check the browser compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 39):

You want to create an Object, not an Array.

Like so,

```
var Map = {};

Map['key1'] = 'value1';
Map['key2'] = 'value2';
```

You can check if the key exists in multiple ways:

```
Map.hasOwnProperty(key);
Map[key] != undefined // For illustration // Edit, remove null check
if (key in Map) ...
```

Comment: This `Map[key] != null && Map[key] != undefined` is not reliable and should not be used (even more: it's plain wrong).

Comment: Plain wrong in what sense... It's checking to see if a value is null or undefined, depending on what he wants to do that may help :\...

Comment: A value can be both `null` and `undefined`, this does not imply the property does not exist. *Plus* `undefined` can be redefined in JavaScript (try it!), so I would never rely on that.

Comment: If you redefine `undefined` you deserve any errors it causes. null indicates a deliberate non-value, whereas undefined indicates an uninitialized variable. Just because `null == undefined` will return true, doesn't mean null is exactly the same as undefined.

Comment: I would never redefine `undefined`. But others might, since nothing keeps them from it. Say I'd create a jQuery plugin for the general public to use, I would not rely on `!= undefined`. Better to use `typeof(val) != "undefined"`. It's just one of those tripwires to fall over. Regarding `!= null` - your wording was *"you can check if the key exists..."* which is exactly what you *can't* with this check.

Comment: `var x = {}; x['key1'] == undefined; // true`. I get your point, that you can assign key1 to the literal value, undefined, but as that means uninitialized I'd still consider that a valid check. I do concede that null does represent an deliberate non-value, which would be proper use of the key and checking for null is not exactly what he wanted and have edited to reflect.

Comment: `var x = {}; undefined = true; x.key1 = undefined; x.key1 === undefined; /* true */ x.key1 === true; /* true */ typeof x.key1 === "undefined"; /* false */`

Comment: More to the point: `var x = {}; x['key1'] = undefined; x['key1'] == undefined; // true`.  So, would you say that `key1` exists?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in` operator: e.g. `"key1" in a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( a['desiredKey'] !== undefined )
{
   // it exists
}
```

Comment: A key might exist but have an undefined value.