# How to use "each" and "for" correct?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

How is a "map" and "for" done correct in this code below? First its getting all the unique id's and then I'm trying to combine the variables from to several "each" and use it in the ajax later on.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#export').on('click',function(){
        var contentMap = {};
        $('[id^="textHolder"],[id^="imgHolder"]').each(function(){
            contentMap[this.id] = $(this).html();
        });
        $('[id^="youtubeHolder"]').each(function(){
            var YoutubeSrc = $('iframe',this).attr('src');
            var YoutubeHolderID = $(this).attr('id');
        });
        for(id in contentMap) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "post.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { 
                    ExportDivID: id,
                    ExportDivContent: contentMap[id],
                    ExportYoutubeSrc: YoutubeSrc,
                    ExportYoutubeHolderID: YoutubeHolderID
                },
                success: function(){
                   alert("success");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }   
          }); 
      }

    });
});
```

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

for loop explained:
[Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

map explained:
[How to create a hash or dictionary object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-a-javascript)

change

```
for(id in contentMap) { .... }
```

to

```
for (var i=0; i<contentMap.length; i++){

    if (contentMap[i] == this.id){

            $.ajax({
                url: "post.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { 
                    ExportDivID: this.id,
                    ExportDivContent: contentMap[this.id],
                    ExportYoutubeSrc: YoutubeSrc,
                    ExportYoutubeHolderID: YoutubeHolderID
                },
                success: function(){
                   alert("success");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }   
          }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i've spent more time with this today, but other than spotting one more syntax issue here: $('iframe',this).attr('src'); .. which should be: $('iframe').attr('src'), i can't offer more help. Sorry.