# Fast way to find if a string is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

In Ruby, finding out if a string is in an array (`.include? x`) is very slow. If you change that array into a set, then **BAM**, lightning fast lookups.

In JavaScript, where there are no sets, array lookups (`.indexOf(x) >= 0`) are also **very** slow, however I need to be doing 10,000s of these lookups in a script.

My Ruby version (with sets) runs in `0.125` seconds, my JavaScript version (in NodeJS) takes `29`!

Is there a any set library or better way to perform array lookups that could get the Javascript speed near the Ruby?

**Edit:** Changed "objects" to "strings" to clear up any confusion

Comment: What's the structure of the objects? If they have some sort of id property that is unique you could store them in an object using that id as the key.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's just an array of strings (`["foo", "bar", "baz"]`). Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: what are you using to benchmark?

Comment: Unique strings? Try an object `var o = {"foo":1,"bar":1,"baz":1}`, and then `if ("foo" in o) { /*exists*/ }`.

Comment: @asifrc The `time` command

Comment: Did you try timing the `"string" in foo` mentioned above?

Comment: (it works on arrays as well, in case @nnnnnn's object thing threw you off)

Comment: @asifrc Wow, it works flawlessly! Script completes in `0.250` seconds! Thanks everyone!

Comment: if its a full string match, startsWith will be faster as indexOf scans all chars. since there might not be startsWith in js, write your own.

Comment: This has been answered many times, js may not have a hashset but does have associative arrays (aka hashmap), see 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript) 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877666/how-is-a-javascript-hash-map-implemented) and 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-a-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, there is some fundamental confusion here about what data structures are available in JavaScript.

**TL;DR**

- If you want fastest key lookup for objects with short prototype inheritance chain use `in`.
- If you want the same, but for the objects with extensive inheritance chain, use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`
- If you want the fastest value lookup, use `Array.prototype.indexOf` for `Array`.
- There isn't a built in function for value lookup in hash-tables. You can, of course, roll your own, but there are many libraries that provide one already. For example, Underscore provides one (it calls it `indexOf`).

**JavaScript has no arrays**

Fundamentally, JavaScript has only hash-tables. The standard `Array` function constructs hash-tables (I will call these *integer hash-tables*, or *int-hash-tables*) where the keys are integers in addition to string keys. These perform similarly to arrays, but they differ in certain ways. There are cons and pros. For example, deleting an element from int-hash-table is an O(1) operation, while deleting an element from array is an O(n) operation (because you need to copy the rest of the elements into the new array). This is why `Array.prototype.splice` function in JavaScript is very fast. The downside is the complexity of implementation.

So, when you say `Array` in JavaScript context it is understood as int-hash-table, and all the asymptotic complexity associated with it. This means that if you wanted to find a string *value* inside an int-hash-table, then it would be an O(n) operation. There is a standard function for doing it: `Array.prototype.indexOf`. However, if you wanted to look for the *key*, then there are two functions: `in` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Somewhat counterintuitively:

```
[1, 2, 3].hasOwnProperty(0); // true
0 in [1, 2, 3]; // true
```

The difference between the two needs further explaining. It is related to the fact that all things in JavaScript are objects, and thus they have some object-y features. One such features the `prototype`, the link between the object and it's prototype. It is a hierarchical structure of hash-tables, each containing properties of objects.

- `in` looks up the immediate hash-table of the object and then recursively searches the hash-tables of the prototypes of this objects.
- Whereas `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` only looks into the immediate hash-table. You might think it should be faster, but wait jumping to conclusions.

Due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript all function calls are dynamic and the environment must take a lot of care to ensure fail-safe code execution. This means that in JavaScript function calls are very expensive. So, going through `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` may be a lot more expensive then going through `in`, even though theoretically it should be the opposite. However, given tall-enough inheritance tree and enough of inherited properties, eventually, `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` will take over.

Some examples to get a better intuition:

```
>>> var array = [1, 2, 3];
undefined
>>> 3 in array;
false
>>> array.hasOwnProperty(3);
false
>>> 3 in array;
false
>>> array.__proto__ = [1, 2, 3, 4];
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 3 in array;
true
>>> array.hasOwnProperty(3);
false
```

Comment: See the benchmarks in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074727/502457) to see a real-world speed comparison.

Answer (score 9):

From @nnnnnn in the comments:

Convert the array into an object, something like this:

```
object = {}
array.forEach(function(string) { // Not cross-browser compatible, it's just an example
  object[string] = 1;
}
```

Then perform lookups like this:

```
if (string in object) {
```