# How do I add values to an array in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to create a new key-value or associative array "gradepoints" using two old arrays "grades" and "array". I tried with and without curly braces in the loop.

```
var gradepoints = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    gradepoints[i] = {array[i] : grades[array[i]] };
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-a-javascript

Comment: check this gradepoints[array[i]] = grades[array[i]];

Comment: @Royi grades is like {'a': 10, 'b: 9, 'c': 8} and array is like {a,b,c}

Comment: @look at Johan's answer. you need to use push.

Comment: Thanks guys (specially Alexander), I just wanted to use an object not array. For anyone looking for a solution, use gradepoints.push

Answer (score 1):

```
var gradepoints = {};
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    gradepoints[array[i]] = grades[array[i]];
}
```