# How to iterate through a JavaScript string without using charAt(), or does it even matter?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript n00b here. I have the following block of code in the webpage I'm making:

```
    for (var k = 0, n = startingText.length; k < n; ++k)
    {
        if (startingText[k] in map1)
            ++map1[startingText[k]];
        else
            map1[startingText[k]] = 1;
    }
```

However, I presume this can and should be optimized. I don't want to have to call the access operator on `startingText` when I'm iterating through its elements sequentially. Or does it matter? I learned C++ before I tried learning JavaScript, so my intuition says there must exist some JavaScript equivalent of iterating through the pointers to the characters of `startingText` and dereferencing them to get their values.

Comment: It does according to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-a-javascript

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't matter. Even your `for` loop has a premature an unnecessary optimization: Just use `string.length`. Don't cache that value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < startingText.length; ++i) {
  var ch = startingText[i];

  // ...
}
```

JavaScript is not C++, and it has completely different performance characteristics. Trying to apply C++/pointer-specific optimizations isn't going to yield noticeable benefits, and it's just going to produce unnecessarily complex code.

> I presume this can and should be optimized

Your presumption is wrong; it should be optimized for speed if you find it's actually a performance bottleneck. Otherwise, it should be optimized for maintainability/readability.