# Merge two arrays into one javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of data. In `a` there are 10 fields and in `b` there are 10 fields

```
var a = [ "siddharth", "sid", "anything", "something", "nothing", ]
var b = [ "23", "67", "10", "10", "90" ]
```

I am trying to create a `JSON` from these arrays as `a` as the key and `b`
as values, as shown below:

```
{  "siddharth" : "23",  "sid" : "67" }
```

How can I achieve this using `javascript` or `jquery`. My current code is

```
 var convert = '{'+datatest.columnHeaders[i].name +":"+datatest.rows[0][i]+'}';
         pair   = convert;/*JSON.stringify(convert);*/
         array.pairArray.push(pair);
```

Comment: Duplicate question? Isn't JSON.stringify(convert); working?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming both arrays are always the same length:

```
var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    //or check with: if (b.length > i) { assignment }
    obj[a[i]] = b[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a = [ "siddharth", "sid", "anything", "something", "nothing" ];
var b = [ "23", "67", "10", "10", "90" ];

var c = {};
$.each( a, function(i,v) {
  c[ v ] = b[ i ];
});

$('body').append( JSON.stringify(c) );
//Output: {"siddharth":"23","sid":"67","anything":"10","something":"10","nothing":"90"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This example is equal to tymeJVs example, but uses forEach loop for array. For me it looks shorter.

```
var obj = {};
a.forEach(function(item, i) {
    obj[item] = b[i];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {"siddharth":"23","sid":"67","anything":"10","something":"10","nothing":"90"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shortest i can get using ES6 fat arrow function, map, reduce & [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
var a = ["siddharth", "sid", "anything", "something", "nothing", ]
var b = ["23", "67", "10", "10", "90"]

const mergeArrToJSON = (a, b) => a
    .map((item, i) => ({[item]: b[i]})) 
    .reduce((json,val)=>Object.assign({},json,val))

console.log(mergeArrToJSON(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create plain object and use it as the mapping container:

```
var a = [ "siddharth", "sid", "anything", "something", "nothing" ];
var b = [ "23", "67", "10", "10", "90" ];
var obj = {};
for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    obj[a[i]] = b[i];
}
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Please refer to [How to create a hash or dictionary object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-javascript) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You would need quotation marks around the name and the value, otherwise you end up with a string like `{siddharth:23,sid:67}`:

```js
// mock the data
var datatest = {
  columnHeaders: [ { name: "siddharth" }, { name: "sid" }, { name: "anything" }, { name: "something" }, { name: "nothing" } ],
  rows: [[ "23", "67", "10", "10", "90" ]]
};

var json = '{';
for (var i = 0; i < datatest.columnHeaders.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) json += ',';
  json += '"' + datatest.columnHeaders[i].name + '":"' + datatest.rows[0][i]  +'"';
}
json += '}';

// show result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add another famous third-party javascript utility library

Lodash, use [zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs/#zipObject):

```
_.zipObject(a, b);
```

Underscore, use [object](http://underscorejs.org/#object):

```
_.object(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use additional plugin then

> [UNDERSCORE](http://underscorejs.org/)

is what you are looking for

```
_.object(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]);
=> {moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}
```

Single line code.
Just include this js

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js
```