# How to merge two arrays into an object where values are assigned to names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

My two arrays are:

```
const values = ['Master Clean', '45', '650']
const names = ['servicemenus.$.name', 'servicemenus.$.duration', 'servicemenus.$.cost']
```

The result should be like this:

```
{ 'servicemenus.$.name':'Master Clean',  'servicemenus.$.duration': '45', 'servicemenus.$.cost': 650}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you tried just iterating one of the arrays using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the index of the array in a `forEach` to refer to the other and dynamically build the object keys:

```
const values = ['Master Clean', '45', '650']
const names = ['servicemenus.$.name', 'servicemenus.$.duration', 'servicemenus.$.cost']

let update = { };

names.forEach( (name,idx) => {
  update[name] = values[idx];
});
```

And that gives you the result

Answer (score 1):

Since I think that you know these two Arrays needs to be the same length at all time. This `for` loop could help you:

```js
const values = ['Master Clean', '45', '650']
const names = ['servicemenus.$.name', 'servicemenus.$.duration', 'servicemenus.$.cost']
var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  //or check with: if (values.length > i) { assignment }
  obj[names[i]] = values[i];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Output will be this: 
`Object { servicemenus.$.name: "Master Clean", servicemenus.$.duration: "45", servicemenus.$.cost: "650" }`

For completion, I found this Question could help you too: [Merge two arrays into one Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124979/merge-two-arrays-into-one-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

From the assumption that the two arrays are always equal length, we can use one of them as the basis for a loop where we build the object:

```
let resultingObject = {};
names.forEach((name, i) => {
    resultingObject[name] = values[i];
});

console.log(resultingObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) an array to a single value (`object` in your case). `Reduce` function accepts accumulator, current value and `index` which you can use to reference a value in the second array. [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) constructs an object with your keys/values.

```js
const values = ['Master Clean', '45', '650'];
const names = ['servicemenus.$.name', 'servicemenus.$.duration', 'servicemenus.$.cost'];

const res = names.reduce((acc, cur, i) => Object.assign(acc, {[cur]: values[i]}), {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

And with for in,loop through the object properties and assign it new object

```
var newobj = {};
for( var i in names){
newobj[names[i]] = values[i];
}
console.log(newobj);
```