# Convert two array into JSON object

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I am trying to build JSON from two array. One array contains field_name and other contains field_value of corresponding field_name

```
    var field_name = ["sys_id","country","calendar_integration","user_password","last_login_time"]
var field_value = ["6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441","United State","Outlook","Password1","2019-03-19 09:48:41"];
```

Expected output:

```
output = { "sys_id" : "6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441",
        "country" : "United State",
        "calendar_integration" : "Outlook",
        "user_password": "Password1",
        "last_login_time": "2019-03-19 09:48:41"
        }
```

Anyone can help here, how to achieve this in JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two arrays into one Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124979/merge-two-arrays-into-one-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `reduce()`.Set value from `field_name` at index `i` as key and value as `field_value` at current index

```js
var field_name = ["sys_id","country","calendar_integration","user_password","last_login_time"]
var field_value = ["6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441","United State","Outlook","Password1","2019-03-19 09:48:41"];

let res = field_name.reduce((ac,a,i) => ({...ac,[a]:field_value[i]}),{});
console.log(res);
```

You can also use `forEach()` in the same way.

```js
var field_name = ["sys_id","country","calendar_integration","user_password","last_login_time"]
var field_value = ["6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441","United State","Outlook","Password1","2019-03-19 09:48:41"];
let obj = {};
field_name.forEach((a,i) => obj[a] = field_value[i]);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks Maheer, this is perfect !!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that if both array are always with the same size :

```
let JSONOutput = {}

for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    JSONOutput[firstArray[i]] = secondArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
var output = {};
field_name.forEach((field, index) => {
     output[field] = field_value[index];
 });
```

Comment: user8276566 Welcome to SO and thanks for your help. Will be nice if you can explain a bit why your answer will solve the question to give it the right context