# Create key value pair dynamically in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

key details: ["100", "101", "102", "103"]
member details : ["CHRIS", "ALYSSA", "DIMPLE", "MEETA"]

How can I create a key value pair dynamically, so that key would be member details and corresponding value will be Key details? Size and value of array is also dynamic, getting through some API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two arrays into one javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124979/merge-two-arrays-into-one-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Array.reduce` to accomplish it:

```js
const values = ["100", "101", "102", "103"];
const keys = ["CHRIS", "ALYSSA", "DIMPLE", "MEETA"];

const result = keys.reduce((carry, key, index) => (carry[key] = values[index], carry), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keys = ["100", "101", "102", "103"];
const members = ["CHRIS", "ALYSSA", "DIMPLE", "MEETA"];


const result = {};
keys.forEach((value, i) => result[members[i]] = value);
console.log(result);
```