# check and remove duplicate coordinate x, y canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to check the coordinate x and y which is duplicated, then remove those existing objects and generate the new one in Canvas world objects. Could anyone kindly gimme a solution. A simple test jsfiddle would be appreciate. Thanks you in advance !

Comment: you should post a case, with a snippet or fiddle, of what you have and what you expect!

Comment: A simple "ask jsfiddle" would be more appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map in javascript then add those co-ordinates in the map. If the co-ordinates are repeated, you can go for creating a new one.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-map-object-in-javascript) question to implement a map in javascript.

Comment: better to use [ES6 Map](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html) collection instead of old school js hacks