# Create image categorie array of object from images object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have following array of Object

```
$scope.images = [
      {key: 'shop1/images/a1.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a2.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a3.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop3/images/a4.jpg'}    
    ]
```

I want to following array of object from above json

```
[
      { 'key':'shop1', 'images':['shop1/images/a1.jpg', 'shop1/images/a3.jpg'] }
      { 'key':'shop2', 'images':['shop2/images/a2.jpg'] }
      { 'key':'shop3', 'images':['shop3/images/a4.jpg'] }
 ]
```

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ojehojf8/

Comment: Its working in fiddle. Whats the issue?

Comment: I want to push key path in image array when key is same  
Like following:  
{ 'key':'shop1', 'images':['shop1/images/a1.jpg', 'shop1/images/a3.jpg'] }

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have an array?

just use a object like mentioned in here [How to create a hash or dictionary object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298169/how-to-create-a-hash-or-dictionary-object-in-javascript)

should be something like the following

```
angular.forEach($scope.images, function(obj){
    $scope.imgsObj = {};
    var res = obj.key.split("/");
    if($scope.imgsObj[res[0]]){
      $scope.imgsObj[res[0]].push(obj);
    }else{
      $scope.imgsObj[res[0]] = [obj];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Angular for this:

```js
var images = [
      {key: 'shop1/images/a1.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a2.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a3.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop3/images/a4.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a5.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a6.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a7.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a8.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop3/images/a9.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a10.jpg'}      
]

// First of all, we collect the data by key
var result = {};
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let key = images[i].key.split('/')[0];
  if (!result[key]) {result[key] = [];}
  result[key].push(images[i].key);
}

// Now we transform them in the result you want
var arr = [];
for (let i in result) {
  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
  arr.push({key: i, images: result[i]});
}

console.log(arr)
```

Just for fun, a one line implementation of the same function:

```js
var images = [
      {key: 'shop1/images/a1.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a2.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a3.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop3/images/a4.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a5.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a6.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a7.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop1/images/a8.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop3/images/a9.jpg'},
      {key: 'shop2/images/a10.jpg'}      
]



var result = images.map(img => img.key.split('/')[0]).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).map(k => {return {key: k, images: images.filter(img => img.key.split('/')[0] === k).map(img => img.key)}});
console.log(result)
```